# Using a Configmap to define whitelist annotations across multiple Ingresses

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

In Kubernetes, is it possible to use a Configmap for the value of an annotation? The reason I want to do this is to reuse an IP whitelist across multiple ingresses. Alternatively, is there another way to approach this problem?

Comment: you could use helm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no feature does it in Kubernetes. But as [iomv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4501268/iomv) wrote, you could try to use [helm.](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#quickstart-guide)

Helm allows you to use variables in your charts, for example:

```
metadata:
{{- if .Values.controller.service.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.controller.service.annotations | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
  labels:
{{- if .Values.controller.service.labels }}
{{ toYaml .Values.controller.service.labels | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
    app: {{ template "nginx-ingress.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    component: "{{ .Values.controller.name }}"
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  name: {{ template "nginx-ingress.controller.fullname" . }}
```

This part of code is from the [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml) chart.
As you see, you can fetch this chart and update the values as you need.

Comment: Is it possible to use helm for templating locally, without needing to install helm on the cluster?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you need to install it inside the cluster too.

Comment: I have a similar issue that I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211284/populating-aws-alb-ingress-annotations-from-configmap
I can understand how helm can be used to create the template, but how does the configmap populate the values in annotation section?